# I am trying to write a simple script in Go but get bad interpreter: Permission denied error

Tags: scripting, go

I am trying to write a script in Go but I get this error:

> bad interpreter: Permission denied

My super simple script is as follow:

```
#!/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.2/bin  
fmt.Println("Hello World")
```

I don´t know if this is possible but I would really like to write scripts in Go since I like the language a lot.

Comment: Even if go were interpreted rather than compiled, `/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.2/bin` is almost certainly a directory, not an executable file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go isn't a scripting language. Like in C you have to compile your source code to make an executable.

From the ["Getting Started"](http://golang.org/doc/install) :

> Create a file named hello.go and put the following program in it:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

> Then run it with the go tool:

```
$ go run hello.go
hello, world
```

In the spirit of Python, there are attempts to make Go scripts kinda possible. Here's for example what you can do with [gorun](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/gorun) :

```
#!/usr/bin/gorun

package main

func main() {
    println("Hello world!")
}
```

But that's not really the logic of Go and that's not nearly as simple as what you typed in your question.